# I own the script but it says "You do not have permission to access the requested document." - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that user will log their time and will be saved to our spreadsheet. All of a sudden, users can't access the deployed script anymore. Even me.

Error says:

> You do not have permission to access the requested document.

Even if using /dev URL, I can't access. I also tried republishing a new version and deployed accessing to anyone even anonymous, but it didnt worked.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `/exec` url instead?

Comment: yes I did, but same error.

Comment: Have you tried republishing a new version? On second thought, could you add everything you tried so far to the question?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well.

Comment: Try to isolate the issue. See [mcve]. First step is restart from scratch: Create a new project>new function> return "hello world">see if that works and take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the problem solved.

I lost access to my google sheet that's why. How silly I am.